# Jssor Delay Caption Out

Tags: javascript, slide, jssor

There a way to set a delay to Caption Transition OUT?

I read documentation, but i not noticed if exist this possibility.

I think that if exist $PlayOutMode: 3, should have a option to set delay to transitions out.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $AutoPlayInterval (in millisecond) option specifies idle period between 'play in' and 'play out'.

Also, the 'd2' attribute can specify delay of an individual caption element.

```
<div u="caption' t="transition1" t2="transition2" d2="500" ...>
```

And the 'b2' attribute can specify the absolute begin time of and individual caption element.

```
<div u="caption' t="transition1" t2="transition2" b2="500" ...>
```

http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-caption-jquery.html

Comment: Thanks @jssor. i'll try implement today. I tried search this in doc but i not find. :(

Comment: At the bottom of http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-caption-jquery.html, you will see 'Caption Transition Fine Tuning (Advanced)' section

Comment: In the section, you can see comment about 'd', 'du', 'x', 'y' ... for transition 't'

Comment: In the same manner, you can specify 'd2', 'du2', 'x2' ... for transition 't2'.